# Read string of numbers into a grid/matrix

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how can I read this grid into arrays like a[i][j] ? I searched on google but I can't seem to find anything useful.Thank you very much for helping!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       String grid =    "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08" +
                        "49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00" +
                        "81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65" +
                        "52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91" +
                        "22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80" +
                        "24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50" +
                        "32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70" +
                        "67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21" +
                        "24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72" +
                        "21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95" +
                        "78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92" +
                        "16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57" +
                        "86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58" + 
                        "19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40" +
                        "04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66" +
                        "88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69" +
                        "04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36" +
                        "20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16" +
                        "20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54" +
                        "01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";

     int[] a = new int[20];

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < 20; j++)
            {

            }


    }
```

Comment: I see a good start of the code, but nothing to "extract" the numbers. To make this problem easier, write the strings such that each "line" also *ends* in a space: `"01 .. 48 " +`. Then each number can be found at a specific offset based on i and j and `string.Substring` can be used to extract it directly; or `string.Split(" ")` can be used to turn the original string into a 1D array which can also be indexed (based on i and j) or iterated.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I'm doing Project Euler. Got here and I can't seem to find anyhting to extract the numbers. I only found the java extracting method but on this one, didn't seem to find one. I did int[][] a = new int[][]; but it gives me error, I don't know how to have an array with 2 coordinates...

Comment: Arrays *must* be given a size when they are are created as their size cannot be changed later. In C#, `new int[20][]` (of type `int[][]`) would create a *jagged array* (create array that can hold 20 arrays, each sub-array being null and must be created explicitly later) and `new int[20,20]` (of type `int[,]`) would create a [*Multidimensional Array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). The m-dimensional array feature would be a good fit for this task.

Comment: Your main problem is that the last number of each line is going to be combined with the first number of next line; there's no separator between the two. As @user2864740 pointed out, u should put some kind of separator at the end of each string.

Comment: I fixed this in my original code. I created the int[,] a = new int[20,20]. Now I need to substract the values from the string and turn them into integer numbers using parseint. My problem right now is how to extract them because I know how to convert them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can simply separate your numbers and use split string. for example:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String grid = "08,02,22,97,38,15,00,40,00,75,04,05,07,78,52,12,50,77,91,08," +
                      "49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,04,56,62,00," +
                      "81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,03,49,13,36,65," +
                      "52,70,95,23,04,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,01,32,56,71,37,02,36,91," +
                      "22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80," +
                      "24,47,32,60,99,03,45,02,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50," +
                      "32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70," +
                      "67,26,20,68,02,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,08,40,91,66,49,94,21," +
                      "24,55,58,05,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72," +
                      "21,36,23,09,75,00,76,44,20,45,35,14,00,61,33,97,34,31,33,95," +
                      "78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,03,80,04,62,16,14,09,53,56,92," +
                      "16,39,05,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,00,17,54,24,36,29,85,57," +
                      "86,56,00,48,35,71,89,07,05,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58," +
                      "19,80,81,68,05,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,04,89,55,40," +
                      "04,52,08,83,97,35,99,16,07,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66," +
                      "88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,03,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69," +
                      "04,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,08,46,29,32,40,62,76,36," +
                      "20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,04,36,16," +
                      "20,73,35,29,78,31,90,01,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,05,54," +
                      "01,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,01,89,19,67,48";

        var splitstring = grid.Split(',');
        var a = new int[20,20];

        const int rowCount = 19; //counts 0 as 1
        var rowIndex = 0;
        var colIndex = 0;

        foreach (var s in splitstring)
        {
            if (rowIndex > rowCount)
            {
                rowIndex = 0;
                colIndex++;
            }
            a[colIndex, rowIndex] = Int32.Parse(s);
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Note the `Int32.Parse(s)` will throw an exception if the parse fails. You can instead use an `Int32.TryParse` and use the out value for your result. Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider add a space to the end of each "line" such as the following:

```
String grid =    "08 02 .. 91 08 " +
                 "01 70 .. 67 48 ";
                             // ^-- add space here
```

This will allow the string to be converted trivially into a 1D array of strings with `string.Split`.

```
string grid = "08 02 .. 91 08";       // every number is space-separated now
string[] gridArray = grid.Split(" "); // -> ["08", "02", .. "91", "08"]
```

(Even without ensuring the extra spaces, a 1D array can be achieved using a Regular Expression split: `var gridArray = Regex.Split(grid, "(?:\s|(?<=\d{2})(?=\d{2}))")`, but I recommend "normalizing" the input string literals if possible.)

And each index in the resulting 1D array can be accessed as so, where `columns` represents the number of columns of the super-imposed matrix, or the "width" of each row.

```
int columns = 20;
int gridIndex = j * columns + i;      // where j is a *row* and i is a *column*
                                      // for a column-major matrix
string numStr = gridArray[gridIndex]; // and value at the [column,row]
```

Then it's just a matter of converting `numStr` to an integer and assigning it to the appropriate array index.

If every number is separated by a space such that ever number NN is in form "NN " it *also* takes up 3 characters. In this case the intermediate Split can be skipped, using the same idea of indexing into the source as a 1D sequence.

```
int gridNumOffset = (j * columns + i) * 3;
string numStr = grid.Substring(gridNumOffset, 2);
```

(Finding the substring offset even when there is *no* space at the end-of-line can be done using a little bit more math, which is a good exercise and the formula just becomes `(j * columns + i) * 3 + f(i)`, where `f(i)` applies the appropriate offset.)

Another more mundane approach, assuming that the original string cannot be modified to include an end-of-line space/character, is to read in each line as N characters, deal with it, and move on. The concepts from above can be applied:

```
int rowWidth = (columns * 3) - 1; // -1 assuming no line-end space
for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {   // j is *rows*, for column-major matrix
    string rowStr = str.Substring(j * rowWidth, rowWidth);
    string[] row = rowStr.Split(" ");  // 1D array just for this row
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
       string numStr = row[i];
       // Convert and put value into the correct matrix position
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't really understand what you wanted to say. int index1 = j * columns + i; If I want to access "81" which is row 3, column 1, it will be 3*1+1 = 4...but the 4th element of the 1D index is "97"

Comment: I've updated the post. `columns` is the "width" of the matrix - to access row 3, column 1 it would be `3 * 20 + 1` or index 61 (which is "70").